# WDS boot image doesnt want to start

Tags: pxe-boot, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, uefi, windows-pe, boot-loader

I'am using Microsoft Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012 R2. I Have virtual machine of generation 2. My goal is to boot Windows PE boot image from WDS server using PXE.

PXE boot seems OK. WDS starts its bootloader, then I choose boot image from list, boot image is downloaded (**[see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idWDF.jpg)**), but then I got blank black screen.

It seems that I have **incorrect WinPE boot image**, which is not compatible with UEFI, so it is unable to start. **How should I modify the image to work with UEFI?**

Generation 2 is necessary for me, because I want to use synthetic net adapter which can achieve higher bandwidth (1GB/s). But generation 2 enforces UEFI for PXE boot. Otherwise I would have to use emulated legacy net adapter, which is poor 100MB/s, but uses EFI, which works fine with my boot image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that Hyper-V Gen2 is not capable running older (or equal) boot images than Win7. The boot image must be taken from at least Win8 (or WinServer2012) image.

Answer (score 0):

Today Boot.wim created by WDS are all EFI compliant.

iIf you see the transfer of Boot.wim on a EFI client then the boot was EFI. It was bootmgfw.efi the one that triggered the Boot.wim TFTP transfer.

In your case Boot.wim surely fails because of a "missing" driver (Net or Video). Check that out.

Comment: Thaks for advice. The problem was, that Hyper-V Gen2 is not capable running older (or equal) boot images than Win7. The boot image must be taken from at least Win8 (or WinServer2012) image.

Comment: that's interesting thank you for commenting your finding. Probably you should post it as the valid answer.